# How to access the domain suggestion api from whmcs with reseller registrar

Tags: whmcs

Any please help me, how to access the domain suggestion api from whmcs registrar module.

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in the Registrar module's [Availability Checks](https://developers.whmcs.com/domain-registrars/availability-checks/) section.

The [WHMCS Sample Registrar Module](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-registrar-module) has good example on how to implement.

First add the following functions:

- registrarmodule_CheckAvailability
- registrarmodule_GetDomainSuggestions

Then in Setup > Products/Services > Domain Pricing, your module will show up in the Lookup Provider (click change). Once set, your module will be responsible on Check Availability and Domain Suggestions.

Comment: We need to use the command for below, But we need to know what are the parameters we need to pass.                                                                                $ch = curl_init();curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://www.example.com/includes/api.php');curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query(array( 'action' => 'CheckAvailability',            'username' => 'IDENTIFIER_OR_ADMIN_USERNAME',            'password' => 'SECRET_OR_HASHED_PASSWORD', 'domain' => 'example.com', 'responsetype' => 'json',) ));

Comment: I couldn't find CheckAvailability in the API Functions list, may be you mean DomainWhois? check here: https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/domainwhois/

Comment: We checked this api, but its shows the purchased domains are still available status.

Comment: strange! it is should work, I use it in one of my applications. Make sure that when you lookup a registered domain from client area it shows unavailable, if not check whois servers config file. resources/domains/whois.json

Comment: Yes, you are correct we checked the configurations was wrong. Now its working fine. Could you please provide any possible solutions for get the suggestions domain list.

Comment: We are using the domain lookup for resellerclub in the domain pricing section. By using this how to check the domain availability and get the suggestions domains. Kindly provide more details about that.

Comment: Actually, I only tested it by using the example registrar module. I was checking how it works.

Comment: Is there any possible to check the availability by using resellerclub lookup.